# Populating multiple columns with a select dropdown using jquery

Tags: jquery

When the table is initially created, the first row of this table has the list of categories in the select block, which is populated using a jquery shown at the bottom.

```
<tr>
<td align="center">
<span id="catDisplay">
<select id="field1" name="field1">
   <option value="">--select--</option>
   <option value="27">$5.00 off (CAT 27)</option>
   <option value="52">$5.00 off Skip (CAT 52)</option>
</select>
</span>
</td>
<td align="left">
<button id="keywordAdd">+</button>
</td>
</tr>
```

The second row gets added using .insertafter().  But it doesn't seem to trigger the same jquery.

```
<tr>
<td align="center">
<span id="catDisplay2">&nbsp;</span>
</td>
<td>
<span id="prodDisplay2">&nbsp;</span>
</td>
<td align="left">
<button id="keywordAdd">+</button>
<button id="keywordDelete">-</button>
</td>
</tr>
```

Here's the jquery:

```
$('span').each(function(){
  if ($(this).attr('id').match(/catDisplay/)) {
     $(this).load(
    'free_gift_backend.php',
    {   
      query       : "getAllCats"
    });  
  }
});
```

I have also tried

```
$("span[id^=catDisplay]").load(
'free_gift_backend.php',
{ 
  query       : "getAllCats"
},
function(response, status, xhr) { 
   if (status != "error") { 
     $('#field1')
       .change(changeCat);
   }
});
```

which also does not work.  What have I done wrong?

Here's the Row Add logic:

```
$("#keywordAdd").live("click", function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   var  rowCount = $("#keywordTable tbody>tr").length + 1;
   // this should be the rowCount, but if someone has added 
   // after deleting from the middle, it will need to be changed.
   while ($("#catDisplay" + rowCount).exists()) {
       rowCount = rowCount + 1;
   }
   var  html = keywordRow(rowCount);
   $(html).insertAfter('#keywordTable tbody>tr:last');
   // $("#keywordTable tbody>tr #catDisplay" + rowCount).focus();
   var $newrow = $("#keywordTable tbody>tr #catDisplay" + rowCount);
   $newrow.focus();
   $newrow.load(
    'free_gift_backend.php',
    {
      query       : "getAllCats",
      rowCount :    rowCount
    } ,
    function(response, status, xhr) {
       if (status != "error") {
         $(this).children(0)
           .change(changeCat);
       }
    } );
  });
```

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to insert the second row?

Comment: Added to the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting the ".load()" call in the ".live()" call where new rows are created seemed to be the solution to my problem.  I had thought that the span.each call would have worked, but I guess this doesn't work for dynamically added rows(?).

```
 $newrow.load(
        'free_gift_backend.php',
        {
          query       : "getAllCats",
          rowCount :    rowCount
        } ,
        function(response, status, xhr) {
           if (status != "error") {
             $(this).children(0)
               .change(changeCat);
           }
        } );
      });
```

Comment: I was thinking that might be your issue. `$('selector')` just creates an array of what fits the selector criteria at that point in time and `each()` will just loop over that array. Neither of those adds any listening for change events.